# How to Split an array with string to next line in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a field 'Names' in a mongoDB document which needs to be split into next line

```
Names: Array

 0: "abc,xyz,qwerty"
```

RESULT

```
Names: Array

 0: "abc"

 1: "xyz"

 2: "qwerty"
```

Can anyone help me achieve this result using mongoDb aggregation?

I tried using $split but it doesnt give me the results as expected, or maybe I'm using a wrong format

Comment: does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AxbSAJHRM3f) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Asumming "Names" is an array and you want to split each value into the array and create a new one and not a nested array you can try this query:

This query uses `$reduce` and `$map`.

- `$map` is to execute the `$split` into each element in the array. And the result is used as input for `$reduce`.
- `$reduce` is used to flat the array and get the result in a single one and not a nested array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "Names": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$Names",
              "as": "n",
              "in": { "$split": [ "$$n", "," ]
              }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YyokJd6jeMb)